# What happens if I use Z-test instead of T test?

Tags: t-test, z-test

I know that when sample size goes large, they basically give the same result.
My question is that 
what happens if I use z-test instead of t-test when sample size is not large. 
I guess the type I error increases and power increases. Am I correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is little to add to @Glen_b expert and eloquent discussion; rather, there is only room for making concepts less precise with the excuse or intention of appealing to intuition. That being said, here're a couple of plots that helped me come to terms with these concepts:

#### 1. t-Student Distributions have "fatter" tails:

These tend towards the normal distribution as the sample size (or degrees of freedom) increase. Consequently, there are more points lying in the asymptotes, and to determine a certain risk alpha, the cut-off point of the test statistic would have to be slid towards the right (let's leave aside two-tail tests). The comparison is thus:

[image]

#### 2. The farther away the cut-off, the lower the power:

So we slide the cutoff value to the right, and in doing so, we stay within the *NULL* a longer stretch before we reject it. Looking at it from the *alternative* there is a larger area of its corresponding curve sub-tending to the left of the cut-off value (*beta*), and a smaller slice to the right (the *power*). Just like this:

[image]

Notice the funny looking *t-distribution* under the *alternative*, which is a tentative approximation to a *non-central t* with a *delta* parameter of $2$. Under the *NULL* the distribution is central with $2\,df$. The cut-off value for a one-sided risk alpha of $0.5\,\%$ is shown as vertical straight lines on both the Z-test (above in blue) and the t-test (below in red).

Comment: Why do you use a non-central t distribution as distribution for group 2? When we use T test, we always assume both group one and group two are from normal distribution. Then under this assumption, I am thinking about what if I use z-test but not t-test. I really like your first plot which inspired me. Thank you.

Comment: @SiliFan I was a bit reluctant to post these plots because I have unresolved questions myself, but I had gone through the exercise of "visualizing" the concept. So I hope that some of the senior members chip in to purge mistakes. In the meantime, my idea is that we are not talking about the distribution of the variable under study, but rather the distribution of the test statistic - at least that's what I had in mind while working on this. Thanks for your compliments in your comment.

Answer (score 6):

Because the critical values are smaller with the Z, the rejection region is larger.

[image]

So yes, significance level goes up, and consequently the rest of the power curve comes with it, as it does whenever you move the significance level.

[image]

Comment: I had been working on producing some graphs, but I got stuck at the fact that the t distribution is always centered at zero. [Here's what I got](https://github.com/RInterested/PLOTS/blob/master/Z%20versus%20t%20Rejection%20and%20Power)

Comment: @Antoni That's neat. (Actually, it's easy to write t-functions with location and scale parameters).... I'd have drawn the two power-curves myself (edit: I did), but your plot (which corresponds to the power curve as a particular difference in means ("delta") would be important for people less familiar with power calculation.

Comment: I should have mentioned that if you're working out power on t-tests under the alternative you deal with the non-central t.